# Any commands hang inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Any commands hang terminal inside docker container.

I login in container with `docker exec -t php-zts /bin/bash`
And then print any elementary command (date, ls, cd /, etc.)

Command hang

When I press ctrl+c I going back to host machine.
But, if I run any command without container - it's work normally

```
docker exec -t php-zts date
Wed Jan 26 00:04:38 UTC 2022
```

tty is enabled in docker-compose.yml
docker system prune and all cleanups can not help me.

I can't identify the problem and smashed my brain. Please help :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use the flag `-i/--interactive` with `docker run`. Here is [a relevant section of the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/):

> `--interactive , -i`       Keep STDIN open even if not attached

Answer (score 3):

You can try to run your container using -i for interactive and -t for tty  which will allow you to navigate and execute commands inside the container

```sh
docker run -it --rm  alpine
```

In the other hand you can run the container with docker run then execute commands inside that container like so:

- `tail -f /dev/null` will keep your container running.
- `-d` will run the command in the background.

```sh
docker run --rm -d --name container1 alpine tail -f /dev/null 
or
docker run --rm -itd --name container1 alpine sh # You can use -id or -td or -itd
```

- This will allow you to run commands from inside the container.
- you can choose sh, bash, or any other shell you prefer.

```sh
docker exec -it container1 alpine sh
```